# Best input size of a the first layer 1D CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to build a 1D CNN with time series. The input is of length 500. There are (only) 2 labels. The architecture which I built so far is the following: there are 3 convolution layers each, of them followed by an activation layer. The first convolution layer takes 50 channels as input.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
import random

class Simple1DCNN3(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Simple1DCNN5, self).__init__()
        self.sequence = nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=50, 
                                          out_channels=64, 
                                          kernel_size=5, 
                                          stride=2),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=64, 
                                          out_channels=128, 
                                          kernel_size=3),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=128, 
                                          out_channels=256, 
                                          kernel_size=1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
        )
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256, 2)

        

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(1, 50,-1)
        
        for layer in self.sequence:
            x = layer(x)
            print(x.size())
        x = x.view(1,-1)
        #print(x.size())
        x = self.fc1(x)
        #print(x.size())
        return x

net = Simple1DCNN3()

input_try = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, 500)
input_try = torch.from_numpy(input_try).float()
net(input_try)
print("input successfull passed to net")
input_try_modif = input_try.view(1, 50,-1)
print(input_try.shape)
print(input_try_modif.shape)
```

As far as I understood, that forced me to segment the input in 10 segments of 50 timepoints. Am I understanding it wrong ? Wouldn't it be wiser to construct the first layer with 500 channels as inputs and have a sliding window kernel? I tried it in the following other script but got the following error message

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
import random

class Simple1DCNN4(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Simple1DCNN5, self).__init__()
        self.sequence = nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=500, 
                                          out_channels=64, 
                                          kernel_size=5, 
                                          stride=2),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=64, 
                                          out_channels=128, 
                                          kernel_size=3),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=128, 
                                          out_channels=256, 
                                          kernel_size=1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
        )
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256, 2)

        

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(1, 50,-1)
        
        for layer in self.sequence:
            x = layer(x)
            print(x.size())
        x = x.view(1,-1)
        #print(x.size())
        x = self.fc1(x)
        #print(x.size())
        return x

net = Simple1DCNN4()

input_try = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, 500)
input_try = torch.from_numpy(input_try).float()
net(input_try)
print("input successfull passed to net")
input_try_modif = input_try.view(1, 50,-1)
print(input_try.shape)
print(input_try_modif.shape)
```

Error message:

```
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 500, 5], expected input[1, 50, 10] to have 500 channels, but got 50 channels instead
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to the answer of @ghchoi, here is the code of the working kernel. For this, I also had to change the kernel size to all the convolutional layers to 1.

```
class Simple1DCNN5(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Simple1DCNN5, self).__init__()
        self.sequence = nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=500, 
                                          out_channels=64, 
                                          kernel_size=1, 
                                          stride=2),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=64, 
                                          out_channels=128, 
                                          kernel_size=1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=128, 
                                          out_channels=256, 
                                          kernel_size=1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
        )
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256, 2)

        

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(1, 500,-1)
        
        for layer in self.sequence:
            x = layer(x)
            #print(x.size())
        x = x.view(1,-1)
        #print(x.size())
        x = self.fc1(x)
        #print(x.size())
        return x
```

The kind of data I have is mono-derivation ECG (electrocardiogram) signal of 2 seconds. This is a recording of the electrical signal of the hear. Here is the idea of what a sample could look like (ploted on a 2D graphs), where you have time on the x-axis and voltage/amplitude on the y-axis

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(1, 500, -1) 

        ...

net = Simple1DCNN4()

input_try = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, 5000)
```

In this way, the input for the first `Conv1d` will have the 500 channels.

Comment: Many thanks @ghchoi. That solved the problem, althouth I had to set the kernel size to all the convolutional layer to 1. Do you have any other particular comment about how I could improve the neuronal network?

Comment: @ecjb You must empirically improve your model. A model can be SOTA on one benchmark dataset, however, it could poorly perform on other datasets. Adapting generally used popular models to your data usually requires a lot of hyper parameter tuning. How are your data like?

Comment: Thanks for the advice @ghchoi. My data are 2 seconds sample of electrocardiogram. I added a theoretical sample in the question. Is this more clear?

Comment: When it peaks is the important information you want to capture? By the way, I am working as an NLP researcher.

Comment: when it peaks is not more of interest than the rest of the signal. Actually, we don't know exactly each pattern is of interest. We are more trying to see whether there are some hidden patterns. NLP = Natural Language Processing? Cool!

Comment: @ecjb Not good at signals... You should make different assumptions and try seriously many times. So people usually find popular models and adapt it to their data.